# How to start file download instantly using php headers

Tags: php, download

well I'm just wondering how I can get an mp3 download to start instantly, as oppose to it simply starting to play in the browser when you directly go to it.

Preferably using php headers.

So essentially when you click the file, I want a download box to appear saving save etc. Right now it just opens and starts playing in the browser.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing to download a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php readfile - Force Download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079574/php-readfile-force-download)

Comment: behavior on open is specific to the client-side settings, but you can *suggest* an action (open/save) with `Content-Disposition` header: see e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment

Comment: Possible duplicate of ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a PHP file that "redirects" to the MP3 file, and point your links to that PHP file.

Code as below:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fileName.mp3"');
readfile('originalFile.mp3');
?>
```

Note: The line that sets the Content-Disposition header is the critical one.

Comment: You may want to add that the second `header(...)` declaration makes the ultimate difference. (Eg. when offering an image for download.)