# How to make the video and audio files downloadable?

Tags: php, file, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)
>   [How to start file download instantly using php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371547/how-to-start-file-download-instantly-using-php-headers)

We're working on a converter site, and we want users to download the converted file. How to make the files downloadable? The other problem is the audio files are playing on browsers, but we want all Video and audio file downloadable. Php code.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Content-disposition header should do it:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=some_file.ext");
```

Also including a Content-type header is good practice as well (especially if you are using a php page to serve it):

```
header("Content-type: mime/type");
```

e.x. audio/mpeg (mp3), video/mp4

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Where can I put that code?

Comment: At the top of the php page. The `header()` function must be used _before_ any output.

Comment: It not works fine to me. It downloads the php file, not the output file :(

Comment: See the duplicate references in the comments. They have complete solutions, including how to write the file data to the script.