# Initiate File Download? Wordpress Theme

Tags: image, wordpress, file, download, themes

I'm at the end of my theme! Building the last functions - file downloads.

I've done this before, but I want to make sure I'm actually working according to best practices in wordpress and use of headers.

After a purchase, the user can download a file. The file must be dynamically re-sized and given to them. If its a zip or eps, its simply transferred likewise. This part I can handle.

**The part in question:**

In the wordpress environment, **what is the best way to stimulate a download**? In linking to an external php file, you can't get access to wp functions unless you include `wp_load.php`, which is not good practice. I would need these for validating request.

I thought perhaps I could use some sort of filter/action/hook checking to see if a file is being requested before customer page load? Is there perhaps a way to dynamically zip it via wordpress? This would be a bonus. Doing this without a page refresh would be most ideal.

I hope this question is not overly subjective. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I might be over-complicating it - this thread seems to hit it nicely - [How to start file download instantly using php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371547/how-to-start-file-download-instantly-using-php-headers)